# Is there a way for pandas read_csv to handle erroneous data the same way as it handles missing data?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dbase

For example when I read an old DBase file converted to CSV I found cells with `**` instead of a number in a column that was supposed to hold integer data.
(I suspect that this was due to exceeding the limit for that column `'SOME_COL,N,2,0'` that by design should have values from 0 to 99 and after that there are `**` for 100 and so on)

I read a lot about pandas handling `missing data`, but cannot find anything about `erroneous data`.

So is there a way to do something about such errors?
`ValueError: Unable to parse string "**" at position 4689`

Maybe I should write some custom converter (if that is possible) or there is better way?

Comment: Does specifying `**` as `na_values` help? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @lojza - Yes, that helped to read the wrong CSV without errors. Thanks!